# Where should I look for the document generated using htp package

Tags: sql, database, plsql, oracle11g

I'm working at a project that uses the htp package from PL/SQL. For example, if I run this procedure, where the webpage will appear? How can I see the page generated?

```
     CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE hello AS
     BEGIN
         HTP.HTMLOPEN;           -- generates <HTML>
         HTP.HEADOPEN;           -- generates <HEAD>
         HTP.TITLE('Hello');     -- generates <TITLE>Hello</TITLE>
         HTP.HEADCLOSE;          -- generates </HEAD>
         HTP.BODYOPEN;           -- generates <BODY>
         HTP.HEADER(1, 'Hello'); -- generates <H1>Hello</H1>
         HTP.BODYCLOSE;          -- generates </BODY>
         HTP.HTMLCLOSE;          -- generates </HTML>
     END;
```

If I run:

```
     exec owa_util.showpage;
```

I get the following error:

```
     ERROR at line 1:
     ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
     ORA-06512: at "SYS.OWA_UTIL", line 356
     ORA-06512: at "SYS.HTP", line 665
     ORA-06512: at "SYS.HTP", line 759
     ORA-06512: at "SYS.HTP", line 1115
     ORA-06512: at "SYS.OWA_UTIL", line 347
     ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you are running from sqlplus or not.  There is some initialization you need to do.  Try this:

```
set serveroutput on

 DECLARE
 param_val   owa.vc_arr;


 BEGIN
   param_val (1) := 1;
   owa.init_cgi_env (param_val);
    HTP.HTMLOPEN;           -- generates <HTML>
         HTP.HEADOPEN;           -- generates <HEAD>
         HTP.TITLE('Hello');     -- generates <TITLE>Hello</TITLE>
         HTP.HEADCLOSE;          -- generates </HEAD>
         HTP.BODYOPEN;           -- generates <BODY>
         HTP.HEADER(1, 'Hello'); -- generates <H1>Hello</H1>
         HTP.BODYCLOSE;          -- generates </BODY>
         HTP.HTMLCLOSE;          -- generates </HTML>
  htp.showpage ();

 END;
 /
```

Results with this output:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Hello</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>Hello</H1>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

See this [link](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=865491) from the Oracle forums for more details.